# Google Dataflow write multiple line in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a simple flow which aim is to write two lines in one BigQuery Table.
I use a DynamicDestinations because after that I will write on mutliple Table, on that example it's the same table...
The problem is that I only have 1 line in my BigQuery table at the end.
It stacktrace I see the following error on the second insert

"
status: {
   code:  6
   message:  "Already Exists: Job sampleprojet3:b9912b9b05794aec8f4292b2ae493612_eeb0082ade6f4a58a14753d1cc92ddbc_00001-0"
  }
"

What does it means ? 
Is it related to this limitation ?
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues/550
How can I do the job ?

I use BeamSDK 2.0.0, I have try with 2.1.0 (same result)

The way I launch :

mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=fr.gireve.dataflow.LogsFlowBug -Dexec.args="--runner=DataflowRunner --inputDir=gs://sampleprojet3.appspot.com/ --project=sampleprojet3 --stagingLocation=gs://dataflow-sampleprojet3/tmp" -Pdataflow-runner

```
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    final List<String> tableNameTableValue = Arrays.asList("table1:value1", "table1:value2", "table2:value1", "table2:value2");

    p.apply(Create.of(tableNameTableValue)).setCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
            .apply(BigQueryIO.<String>write()
            .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
            .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
            .to(new DynamicDestinations<String, KV<String, String>>() {
                @Override
                public KV<String, String> getDestination(ValueInSingleWindow<String> element) {
                    final String[] split = element.getValue().split(":");
                    return KV.of(split[0], split[1]) ;
                }

                @Override
                public Coder<KV<String, String>> getDestinationCoder() {
                    return KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), StringUtf8Coder.of());
                }

                @Override
                public TableDestination getTable(KV<String, String> row) {
                    String tableName = row.getKey();
                    String tableSpec = "sampleprojet3:testLoadJSON." + tableName;
                    return new TableDestination(tableSpec, "Table " + tableName);
                }

                @Override
                public TableSchema getSchema(KV<String, String> row) {
                    List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<>();
                    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("myColumn").setType("STRING"));
                    TableSchema ts = new TableSchema();
                    ts.setFields(fields);
                    return ts;
                }
            })
            .withFormatFunction(new SerializableFunction<String, TableRow>() {
                public TableRow apply(String row) {
                    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                    tr.set("myColumn", row);
                    return tr;
                }
            }));

    p.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

Thanks

Comment: DynamicDestinations.getTable() must return different tables for different destinations, but this code ignores the .getValue() component of your KV: can you explain why you're using KV as a destination type, rather than just using table name as a destination type, since the value of the KV is ignored anyway?

Comment: Ok I agree it's not clear. I have updates the code.
The input list present a set of string where first token represent the table.
So at the end we must have two table created with 2 lines on each.
Unfortunatly we have 2 tables but one lines :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DynamicDestinations` associates each element with a *destination* - i.e. where the element should go. Elements are routed to BigQuery tables according to their destinations: **1 destination = 1 BigQuery table with a schema**: the destination should include just enough information to produce a `TableDestination` and a schema. Elements with the same destination go to the same table, elements with different destinations go to different tables.

Your code snippet uses `DynamicDestinations` with a destination type that contains *both the element and the table*, which is unnecessary, and of course, violates the constraint above: elements with a different destination end up going to the same table: e.g. `KV("table1", "value1")` and `KV("table1", "value2")` are different destinations but your `getTable` maps them to the same table `table1`.

You need to remove the element from your destination type. That will also lead to simpler code. As a side note, I think you don't need to override `getDestinationCoder()` - it can be inferred automatically.

Try this:

```
        .to(new DynamicDestinations<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public String getDestination(ValueInSingleWindow<String> element) {
                return element.getValue().split(":")[0];
            }

            @Override
            public TableDestination getTable(String tableName) {
                return new TableDestination(
                    "sampleprojet3:testLoadJSON." + tableName, "Table " + tableName);
            }

            @Override
            public TableSchema getSchema(String tableName) {
                List<TableFieldSchema> fields = Arrays.asList(
                    new TableFieldSchema().setName("myColumn").setType("STRING"));
                return new TableSchema().setFields(fields);
            }
        })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comment, now :  
   it's working fine  
   it's much more clearer in my mind !  
Beam documentation was not so clear